# How to move count to the next row if it is holiday in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008-r2

Input 
Table 1:

```
CountryCode   is_holiday ?   TicketsRaiseDay   NofTickets       TotalTickets
91             No            Mon                10              10
91             No            Tue                20              20
91             Yes           Sat                10              NA (since it is holiday )
91             No            Mon                5               15 (Sat tickets +Monday Tickets )
```

Here totaltickets column is calculated or computed column or report column .

Note : `is_holiday` column is the responsible to hold holiday detail so need not to bother about this field .
It would be great if i can get either ssrs expression or sql code .

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

You can see a working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/feb7e/7).

```
SELECT
    x.countrycode,
    x.is_holiday,
    case when x.previousHoliday = 1 THEN previousNumberOfTickets + x.nofTickets
         when x.is_holiday = 1 then 0
         else x.nofTickets
    end
from (select 
            is_holiday,
            nofTickets,
            countrycode,
            lag(is_Holiday,1) over (order by countrycode) as previousHoliday,
            lag(nofTickets,1) over (order by countrycode) as previousNumberOfTickets           
from tickets) x
```

**Note**: this doesn't handle consecutive holidays. Also, you would probably want to order by something other than countrycode. I wasn't sure what you're ordering by.

**Edit**: I just noticed you're using sql server 2008, and the lag function is not available until 2012.

Comment: Many thanks Michael  for quick reply, Some times we will get 3 consecutive holidays so the logic should apply on holidays. so kindly provide me if any another solutions .

Comment: Hi Micheal I got to know it , i will convert it into sql 2008 by writing inner joins , Kindly let me know if any solution for consecutive holidays .

Comment: There isn't a set based query that will perform this logic.  You'll have to operate on each row using a cursor or while loop.